# PYTHON - Cannot write data from my 2D list into a CSV

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write the contents of two lists to two respective CSVs in Python. The contents of the CSVs are meant to be wiped before being written to, which works, however I am unable to write to the CSVs successfully without an error or nothing writing to them at all.

I have tried code such as *"invWrite = csv.writer(open("INVENTORY.csv",'at'), delimiter=',')"* and using *"writerows"* as well as trying *"invWrite = open("INVENTORY.csv","at")"* and using *"write"* however it all appears to not work, my csv either wiping (when I use the "w" method instead of "at") or staying the same.

Trying to utilise "map()" and doing playerWrite.writerows(map(str,x)) causes the following error:

```
*line 180, in <module>
    playerWrite.writerow(map(str,x))
_csv.Error: sequence expected*
```

simply typing playerWrite.writerow(x) provides a similar issue as my original problem - the csv is wiped (which is intended and due to the fact I originally called the write function with the "w" method) but nothing is written to it.

I will show the relevant code here, the first half is the lists being written from the CSVs and the latter half being the code for rewriting the CSVs. playerInv is a 2D list.

```
import csv 

playerInfo = []
playerRead = csv.reader(open("playerInfo.csv", 'r'), delimiter=',')
for x in playerRead:
    playerInfo.append(x[0])
playerMoney = str(playerInfo[1])

playerInv = []
invRead = csv.reader(open("INVENTORY.csv", 'r'), delimiter=',')
for x in invRead:
    playerInv.append(x)
```

the writing part:

```
playerWrite = csv.writer(open("playerInfo.csv",'w'), delimiter=',')
invWrite = csv.writer(open("INVENTORY.csv",'w'), delimiter=',')
playerWrite = csv.writer(open("playerInfo.csv",'at'), delimiter=',')
invWrite = csv.writer(open("INVENTORY.csv",'at'), delimiter=',')
for x in playerInfo:
    playerWrite.writerows(str(x))
for x in playerInv:
    invWrite.writerows(str(x))
```

Here is the contents of playerInv (list), passed from INVENTORY.csv before it was wiped:

> [['prisoner rags', '1'], ['training greatsword', '1'], ['battle
>   spinner', '1'], ['granny smiths', '1'], ['skeleton key', '1'],
>   ['bread', '1']] #this is a 2D list.

and here is playerInfo:

> ['playerName', '500'] #normal list

**tl;dr -** I have tried a combination of different methods to call/define my csv writing function and tried a number of ways to write to my csv (write,writerow,etc.) however I am unable to find a way to write my list to my csv. If anyone could solve this issue or provide context as to how I could solve it, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: *Does not appear to work* does note provide useful information for assistance. What happens and which error message/erroneous result do you get?

Comment: *I heard only string values could be written to a CSV*. A csv is a text file, so everything will be converted to a string. But `csv.writerow` will gladly accept a tuple or list containing integers and floating point values. So I would just use: `playerWrite.writerows(playerInfo)`

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that there exist two different methods of csvwriter: `.writerow` and `.writerows`.

*as I heard only string values could be written to a CSV*

Yes, but as [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) says, you should feed `.writerow` with sequence of `str`s, that might be `list` of `str`s - look at example provided for `csv.writer`.

I can't be 100% sure without looking at `playerInv` content, but I think your code for writing should be:

```
for x in playerInv:
    invWrite.writerow(map(str,x))
```

please check if that would help.

Comment: this caused the following error: "_csv.Error: sequence expected". I used this for both playerWrite and invWrite and got the error for both.

Answer (score 0):

No longer require a solution to this problem, able to write to CSV however every character is separated by a comma. I will do my own research into this. Thank you Daweo for referring me to the documentation.